# Can AngularJs select only a directory, not including file name?

Tags: angularjs

As the title says, can AngularJs open a dialog to allow the user to select only a directory (folder), not including file name?

I am selecting a download directory, and the user doesn't get to choose file name, in case they give the wrong extension.

---

[Update] Urk! If I use the standard file dialog, and type a new file name, the browser errors because the file does not exist :-(

Comment: The point of the control is to upload a specific file, what would you want to do with a directory?

Comment: What does it matter? Can't we just assume that I know what I am doing?  As it happens, I am selecting a ***down***load directory, and the user shouldn't get to choose file name, in case they give the wrong extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs of its own does not provide any feature up and above the native DOM api to be able to do this. If it is available in the DOM API, this would be possible.

To answer your question: No. There is no DOM API that allows us to prompt for a dialog box that only selects directories in the visitor's file system.

Comment: A pity, that. I am selecting a download directory, and the user shouldn't get to choose file name, in case they give the wrong extension

Comment: You can set the header Content Disposition: attachment; filename= yourfilename.ext when you serve that file to set the filename for the user. 
But if they have their browser configured to prompt for a save location (which is not the default, and doing so implies some level of tech savvyness ), they will be able to change the file extension.